# Fill multiple textboxes from one autocomplete c#

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I can't think of a nice clean solution nor can I find anything like this for c#.

What I want to do is from one TextBox do an autocomplete with user data (name, lastname, etc.), this works.
I enter the first letter of a name, and the autocomplete shows me the right names.

Now, after I've selected the right user in that first TextBox, I want to auto-fill the others.
Like Zip-code, Street, Adres etc.

This is how I do my Autocomplete atm:

```
class getUsers
{
Database db = new Database();
    public AutoCompleteStringCollection userAutoComplete()
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection acsc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        try
        {
            db.cmd.Connection = db.connection;
            db.connection.Open();
            db.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user";
            OleDbDataReader reader = db.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                acsc.Add(reader["name"].ToString() + " " + reader["lastname"].ToString() + " " + reader["zipcode"].ToString() + " - " + reader["street"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            db.connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

        return acsc;
    }
  }
```

This is the Form load:

```
public partial class users : Form
{
getUsers gK = new getUsers();
    private void users_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = gK.userAutoComplete();
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    }
}
```

Thank in advance, happy holidays!
Cheers

Comment: What are you asking exactly? If your code works for names why not using it also for postal codes (by populating a different autocomplete source)? Logically, the autocomplete feature can only work in case of having a valid source of values to complete the inputs. You can use different properties or create your own list (what you did in your code). Can you please explain better what you want?

Comment: I want a autofill feature, like what you have on browsers. You enter your Name/Username and Chrome fills in the rest for you.

Comment: OK. Use your code to build it, what is the problem? If you provide as suggestions just "my name, your name", it might only show any of these strings. If you provide "my name, your name, 24402, 11132, any other thing, etc.", it would show all that. The autocomplete feature of a browser is more complex than just a few lines of code and, in any case, it accounts for many more elements than just names.

Comment: I read now the last update of your comment: what Chrome does is storing specific information for each field; it creates as many sources as fields. For example: one datasource for fields called "username", another one for fields called "password", etc. There is no in-built functionality, you have to build it by your own: the better performance you want, the more complex will be the algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but can you also just do: "Form frmUsers = new Form();" and then in the getUsers class reader while loop: "frmUsers.TextBox2.Text = reader["lastname"].ToString();" ? Or would that be impossible/inappropriate?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that. What you propose does nothing to do with autocomplete. As explained: if you want to emulate the browsers' functionality you describe (different suggestions for different fields), you would have to create as many datasources as fields you want to complete. Instead of getting the customsources from the DB you might store the last values inputted by the user in the memory/a file. The source is just a collection (like a list) which is ordered on account of the first letters for each item (name in your case). Instead of what you are doing, do:

Comment: `AutoCompleteStringCollection sourceZips sourceZips.Add(reader["zipcode"].ToString());  ...` `AutoCompleteStringCollection sourceStreets sourceStreets.Add(reader["street"].ToString()); ...` and use each of these sources with the corresponding TextBox. You might add further information for each source but understand that the important item is the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, just to answer the question for others, I thought this way was clean enough:

While I loop through my AutoComplete, to add a costumer's name and info into it.
I also add it to a List, which I then can read from in my autoFill.

```
public List<getKlanten> _listklantnr = new List<getKlanten>();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection acsc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    public AutoCompleteStringCollection klantAutoComplete()
    {
        try
        {
            db.cmd.Connection = db.connection;
            db.connection.Open();
            db.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM klant";
            OleDbDataReader reader = db.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                _listklantnr.Add(new getKlanten
                {
                    klantnr = (int)reader["klantnr"],
                });
                if (reader["tussenvoegsel"].ToString().ToUpper() != "")
                {
                    acsc.Add(reader["roepnaam"].ToString().ToUpper() + " " + reader["tussenvoegsel"].ToString().ToUpper() + " " + reader["achternaam"].ToString().ToUpper() + " - " + reader["postcode"].ToString().ToUpper() + " " + reader["huisnummer"].ToString().ToUpper());
                } else {
                    acsc.Add(reader["roepnaam"].ToString().ToUpper() + " " + reader["achternaam"].ToString().ToUpper() + " - " + reader["postcode"].ToString().ToUpper() + " " + reader["huisnummer"].ToString().ToUpper());
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            db.connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        return acsc;
    }
```

So with IndexOf and stuff I can exactly get the costumer I want, and then use the String autoFill method on every other TextBox if the main Textbox triggers the onTextChanged. :)

```
string result;
    public string autoFill(string Tabel, string naamTxtbox)
    {
        try
        {
            result = "";
            int getIndexKlanten;
            getIndexKlanten = (acsc.IndexOf(naamtxtbox));// < 0) ? -1 : acsc.IndexOf(naamtxtbox);
            if (getIndexKlanten > -1)
            {
            db.cmd.Connection = db.connection;
            db.connection.Open();
            db.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * " +
            "FROM klant " +
            "WHERE klantnr = ?";
            db.cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("1", _listklantnr[getIndexKlanten].klantnr.ToString()));
            OleDbDataReader dataReader;
            dataReader = db.cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                    klantresult = dataReader[tabel].ToString();   
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            db.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            db.connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        return klantresult;
    }
```

The code should speak for it's self, it's been a little while already.